# Xamarin.Forms tasks do not match targets

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

Complete Error :- 
Xamarin.Forms.targets(3,3): Error XF002: Xamarin.Forms tasks do not match targets. Please ensure that all projects reference the same version of Xamarin.Forms, and if the error persists, please restart the IDE. (XF002) (BaseBallApp.iOS)

Comment: the error gives you two very explicit instructions to follow - have you tried either of them?

Comment: Yes , i have tried both.

Comment: Make triple sure that all projects have the same Xamarin.Forms version. Also any test projects you might have in your solution. Delete your output folders, rebuild and restart your IDE. That works in 99,9% of the cases for me.